# Catching a dynamic php loop id value for post using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

how do i catch the id mtotal from hidden input :

```
                           <?php
        foreach ($decodeMessages as $messages) {
                print  "
             <div class='row clearfix js-sweetalert'>
                                <div class='col-sm-12'>
                                <form action='' mehtod='POST'>
                                <div class='card message-page'>
                                    <div class='header'>
                                        <h2>
                                           From: " . $messages['Name'] .
                                           "<small>
                                                Email:" . $messages['Email']
                                            ."</small>
                                        </h2>
                                        <ul class='header-dropdown m-r--5'>
                                            <li>
                                            <input type='hidden' id='mtotal' value='".$messages['messageTotal']."' >
                                                <button type='button' onclick='showCancelMessage();' name='".$messages['messageTotal']."' id='".$messages['messageTotal']."' class='btn btn-default waves-effect m-r-20' data-type='cancel'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <div class='body'>";
                                            $iv = chr(0x0) . chr(0x0) . chr(0x0);
                                            print openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($messages['Message']), 'aes-256-cbc', $messages['toUser'], OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
                                   print "</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
             ";
         }

        ?>
```

so far i have tried:

```
   var datastring = $("#mtotal").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            mID: "mID="+datastring
        },
        dataType: "html",
        success: function () {
            swal("Done!", "Message succesfully deleted!"+datastring, "success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            swal("Error deleting!", "Please try again", "error");
        }
    });
```

i added `datastring` to the done to see if it selected the correct id from the div the button was pressed. which was 43 and it outputted `40`.

loop image [loop image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZTXR.png)

**My question is**: How do i catch the dynamic mtotal number from the hidden input and print that specific number which was submitted by the submit button from that div ?

How do i handle that post using PHP on the same page

```
if (isset($_POST['mID'])) {} // that does not work
```

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: `data: { mID: $("#mtotal").val()  }`

Comment: @Alex that displays all the outputs as 40, even if the message selected was id 43. i have updated my post with a view of the looped div output

Comment: are you kidding me? just try this one then `data: { mID: datastring }`

Comment: `onclick='showCancelMessage(".$messages['messageTotal'].");'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating multiple hidden inputs with id "mtotal" in your foreach loop. You have to give unique ids to each hidden input, maybe based on the loop index/key:

```
foreach ($decodeMessages as $key => $messages) {
```

And:

```
<input type='hidden' id='mtotal_" . $key ."' value='".$messages['messageTotal']."' >
```

You should also add this key as data attribute on the corresponding button like this:

```
<button class='cancel-button' type='button' data-key='".$key."'><i class='fa fa-trash-o'></i></button>
```

Furthermore it would be better to use a class for your cancel button as I did above, then add your click handler in your javascript file. You can get the data-key attribute from the button and select your hidden input like this:

```
$('.cancel-button').click(function(){
    var key = $(this).attr('data-key');
    var datastring = $("#mtotal_" + key).val();
    ...
});
```

Comment: it creates the a unique id, although how do i catch which id was the button was submitted in. eg: if post 43 delete button was entered then the post should have mid=43

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how you get the corresponding key

Comment: it returns undefined

Comment: im not sure as to why i cannot seem to get it to print out which one in the loop was selected

Comment: Firstly check if the data-key attributes and the hidden input ids are set properly via the inspect element functionality in your browser

Comment: all the properties have been set.

Comment: I replaced $(this) with the submit div id. it works, now if you select message 2 which is 42, the output displays 0 (0 = msg1) instead of 1 (1= msg2)

Comment: With my updated version you shouldn't replace $(this). Please undo and try again with $(this).

Comment: yes, that worked @iiirxs. Although im not sure why it's not posting or printing out anything for $_POST['mID']. and it's posting on the same page

Comment: it simply prints out empty arrays

Comment: your dataType in your ajax request is wrong. It's set to html but it would be better to set it to json.

Comment: when i set it to json it shows an error, when i remove dataType it passes the deleted message

Comment: yes kind of, except that the ajax after success is not being outputted by print_r($_GET) or print_r($_POST)

Comment: I can't help you with that since you have not posted your code. All I can see is your javascript code on success that seems ok.

Comment: Thanks @iiirxs, that i will have to post in a different question